# Using metric in right hand side of prometheus query

Tags: grafana, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I am using prometheus and grafana to monitor some servers. One of the metrics I have exposed is called `recent_tables`, which contains the number of assets who have written to sql tables in the past 15 minutes (machines automatically post to sql). It's labels are `table`, `job`, and `status_code`. I also have metric `online_assets`, which has the amount of assets that are online. Its labels are `cluster_id`, `db_host`, and `job`.

I am trying to make an alert for when < 90% of online assets have written to sql tables recently. Before I write the alert, I am trying to get a panel in grafana to populate the data and eventually transition this to an alertmanager expr. The following queries do not work, and I don't understand why:

```
recent_tables < online_assets * 0.9

sum(recent_tables) by (table) < online_assets * 0.9
```

However, the following query works:

```
sum(recent_tables{table="<table>"}) - sum(online_assets)
```

I do not want to have to make an alert based on every table (this is possible through ansible), but I would like to understand if there is a way to get multiple vectors out of the same query.

Comment: In order to make an informed answer, we would need the labels of each metric. Best would be a sample.

Comment: Hi Michael, live_assets have cluster_id, db_host, and job labels. Ex; `live_assets{cluster_id="east", db_host="pgserver1", job="live_asset_count"} 2000`. recent_tables has labels job, status_code, and table. Ex; `recent_tables{table="user_accounts", status_code=200, job="recent_user_accounts"} 1500`

Comment: AFAIS, there is no way to relate a table with the corresponding number of assets. What do you want to compare and on which dimension ? You have to indicate to the operators how to match elements (using `ON()`). And if there are more elements on one side, you have to indicate it with `group_left` or `group_right`.

Comment: You were exactly right, I wish I could upvote this response. The query I needed was: `sum(recent_tables) by (table) - ignoring(table) group_left() sum(live_assets) * 0.9 < 0`. I am sure this can be simplified but this will do for now. I was missing the fact that metrics with uneven labels could not be merged. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Michael Doubez pointed out, you cannot have unbalanced label dimensions when making queries.

I ended up with the following:
`sum(recent_tables) by (table) - ignoring(table) group_left() sum(live_assets) * 0.9 < 0`

This accounts for the mismatch in dimensions but there may be a cleaner way.